# How to get id attribute of related object

Tags: django, django-models

I have these two models related to each other. I need to create a sub folder to keep my attachment by qa id.
but I'm struggling with getting id of the related objects id. Can someone please help?

```
class Qa(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Q')
    answer_text = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='A')



class Attachment(models.Model):
    qa = models.ForeignKey('Qa', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files' )
    attach_file = models.FileField(upload_to=f'qa_data/{qa_id}/', null=True, verbose_name='Attachment')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'qa_data_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.qa.id, filename)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    attach_file = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_path)
```

use a custom function to get the `qa_id` and then save it